# Question on designing a binary (integer) programming problem

Tags: constraints, binary-programming

Given a vector $c\in\Re^n$ and a vector $b\in\Re^n$, I would like to design a binary programming problem,
\begin{equation}
\max_{x\in\{1,0\}} c^\top x
\end{equation}
and for constraints, I need all consecutive $1$s in the decision variable $x$ times with corresponding $b$ has the same value.

For example, if $\sum_{k=1}^{4} b_k \approx \sum_{k=8}^{9}b_k \approx \sum_{k=11}^{15} b_k $, then a feasible $x$ would be:
\begin{equation}
x=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where "$\approx$" means that differences are less than given small tolerance.

Can anyone give a suggestion about how to design such constraints? Thanks!

Comment: What is the vector $b$ for your example?

Comment: vector $b$ is a sequence of daily stock log returns

Comment: I mean the explicit numerical values $(b_1,\dots,b_{15})$.

Comment: $b$ sequence has more than 1000 data points, it varies between -0.22 to 0.18, if you need I can provide it

Comment: I'm asking for only $15$ data points to match your example.

Comment: I just arbitrarily use 15 data points as an example to explain my constraints. I picked 40 points of $b$ [-0.051183225 0.006269613 0.030771659 0.016032408 -0.017832006 0.054717834 0.002105465 0.01374827 -0.017579692 -0.026253331 -0.004463147 -0.020738462 -0.012525835 0.009753592 -0.014285957 0.059063644 -0.004057825 -0.02165255 0.008315233 -0.0101061 0.001393174 0.052495833 -0.008623602 -0.05346463 0.009990093 -0.01945239 -0.00064889 0.014079208 0.026681932 -0.025782301 0.004147811 0.045172233 0.015608066 -0.024645797 -0.031191612 0.033607119 0.019041692 0.066673194 0.044714584 -0.007456049]

Comment: Any lower or upper bounds on the length of each run of consecutive $1$s or $0$s?  Or any bounds on the number of runs?

Comment: There is no limits on the length of  each run of consecutive 1s or 0s, as long as the sum of corresponding $b$ are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a network-based mixed integer linear programming formulation.  The nodes are $N=\{0,\dots,n+1\}$, where $s=0$ is the source node and $t=n+1$ is the sink node.  The arcs are $A=\{i\in N, j\in N: i < j\}$.  For $(i,j)\in A$ and $v\in\{0,1\}$, let binary decision variable $y_{i,j,v}$ indicate whether elements $i,\dots,j-1$ form a consecutive run with value $v$.  Let decision variable $z\in [L,U]$ be the common sum of $b_k$ values for each run of $1$s, with constant bounds $L=\sum_{k=1}^n \min(b_k,0)$ and $U=\sum_{k=1}^n \max(b_k,0)$.  Let constant $\epsilon>0$ be the tolerance for $\approx$.  The problem is to maximize
$$\sum_{(i,j) \in A: i \not= 0} \left(\sum_{k=i}^{j-1} c_k\right) y_{i,j,1}$$
subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{(i,j)\in A} y_{i,j,v} - \sum_{(j,i) \in A} y_{j,i,1-v}
    &= [i = s \land v = 0]
   &&\text{for $i \in N \setminus \{t\}$ and  $v \in \{0,1\}$} \tag1 \\
      -\frac{\epsilon}{2}+M_1 (1-y_{i,j,1}) \le z-\sum_{k=i}^{j-1} b_k &\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}+M_2(1-y_{i,j,1}) &&\text{for $(i,j) \in A$ such that $i \not= s$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces flow balance, with a dummy run of $0$s starting at the source.
The (big-M) constraint $(2)$ enforces the logical implication $$y_{i,j,1} = 1 \implies \left|z-\sum_{k=i}^{j-1} b_k\right| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
You can take big-M values
\begin{align}
M_1 &= L-\sum_{k=i}^{j-1} b_k+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
M_2 &= U-\sum_{k=i}^{j-1} b_k-\frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align}

After solving, you can postprocess to compute $x_k=1$ for $k\in\{i,\dots,j-1\}$ for all $(i,j)\in A$ such that $y_{i,j,1}=1$.

For your example data with $\epsilon=0.001$ and randomly generated $c_k$, here is an optimal solution:
\begin{matrix}
i &j &v &y_{i,j,v} \\
\hline
0 &1 &0 &1 \\
1 &10 &1 &1 \\ 
10 &13 &0 &1 \\ 
13 &18 &1 &1 \\
18 &39 &0 &1 \\
39 &41 &1 &1
\end{matrix}
\begin{align}
z &= 0.03755 \\  
\sum_{k=1}^9 b_k &= 0.037050 \\
\sum_{k=13}^{17} b_k &= 0.037948 \\ 
\sum_{k=39}^{40} b_k &= 0.037259
\end{align}
\begin{matrix}
k & b_k & c_k & x_k \\ 
\hline
1 & -0.05118323 & 0.6515976 & 1 \\
2 & 0.00626961 & 0.9214633 & 1 \\
3 & 0.03077166 & -0.4772522 & 1 \\
4 & 0.01603241 & 0.6608215 & 1 \\
5 & -0.01783201 & 0.0680905 & 1 \\
6 & 0.05471783 & 0.8297638 & 1 \\
7 & 0.00210547 & 0.7863591 & 1 \\
8 & 0.01374827 & -0.5370080 & 1 \\
9 & -0.01757969 & 0.3396552 & 1 \\
10 & -0.02625333 & 0.6314154 & 0 \\
11 & -0.00446315 & -0.2994972 & 0 \\
12 & -0.02073846 & -0.0031765 & 0 \\
13 & -0.01252584 & 0.4703300 & 1 \\
14 & 0.00975359 & 0.7840745 & 1 \\
15 & -0.01428596 & 0.3702945 & 1 \\
16 & 0.05906364 & -1.6571357 & 1 \\
17 & -0.00405783 & 0.6717557 & 1 \\
18 & -0.02165255 & -0.3653084 & 0 \\
19 & 0.00831523 & -1.1568648 & 0 \\
20 & -0.01010610 & 0.7950355 & 0 \\
21 & 0.00139317 & -0.1578055 & 0 \\
22 & 0.05249583 & 0.5692947 & 0 \\
23 & -0.00862360 & -0.1551003 & 0 \\
24 & -0.05346463 & -0.6032818 & 0 \\
25 & 0.00999009 & -0.2297138 & 0 \\
26 & -0.01945239 & 0.3247675 & 0 \\
27 & -0.00064889 & -0.6720116 & 0 \\
28 & 0.01407921 & -1.7712827 & 0 \\
29 & 0.02668193 & 0.7281612 & 0 \\
30 & -0.02578230 & -0.3458772 & 0 \\
31 & 0.00414781 & -0.0010739 & 0 \\
32 & 0.04517223 & -1.2890061 & 0 \\
33 & 0.01560807 & -1.5741394 & 0 \\
34 & -0.02464580 & -1.0035068 & 0 \\
35 & -0.03119161 & -1.0080236 & 0 \\
36 & 0.03360712 & 0.2631495 & 0 \\
37 & 0.01904169 & 0.0646314 & 0 \\
38 & 0.06667319 & -0.1402586 & 0 \\
39 & 0.04471458 & 0.3587272 & 1 \\
40 & -0.00745605 & 0.9589894 & 1
\end{matrix}

Comment: Thank you very much RobPratt! I am not familiar with network-based MIP, I am trying to learn it and get back to you ASAP.

Comment: You can use any MILP solver.  By “network-based” formulation, I just meant that the variables and constraints are indexed by the nodes and arcs of an underlying network.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt! For my understanding, the only decision variables are vector $y_{i,j,v}$ and $z$, what is the length of vector $y_{i,j,v}$? should I include all feasible combination of $i$ and $j$?

Comment: The number of $y_{i,j,v}$ variables is $2\binom{n+2}{2}$.

Comment: One more question, for the first constraint to enforce flow balance, do I have to test all the possible paths?  i.e. $(y_{0,1,0} - y_{1,5,1} + y_{5,15,0} - y_{15,41,1})$, $(y_{0,10,0} - y_{10,15,1} + y_{15,27,0} - y_{27,31,1} +  y_{31,34,0} -  y_{31,41,1})$... etc. many thanks!

Comment: No, you don’t explicitly enumerate paths.  Constraint $(1)$ is per node and value, and the LHS is the sum of outgoing arcs with that value minus the sum of incoming arcs with the opposite value.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand the 1st constraint..... For node 2, although $x_2$ to $x_9$ are $8$ consecutive $1$s, $y_{0,2,0} = 0$ and  $y_{1,2,0} = 0$ will ensure that $y_{2,10,1} = 0$.